# Getting Forum Post Contents

Tags: java, html, jsoup

When getting the post contents on a forum I'm having troubles receiving the text that is rendered by the `HTML`. By using `org.jsoup.nodes.Document` and `getElementsByClass` I can retrieve the following snippet:

```
<html>
  <head>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="entry-content">
      <div>
        <div>
          <div align="center">
            Some text...<br>continued in 2nd line<br> and third line. This is <b>bold</b>.
          </div>
          <br>


          <div align="center">
            Also, here's a link:
          </div>
          <div align="center">
            <a href="http://www.google.com/" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">http://www.google.com/</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Pasting this into a HTML online compiler I'll receive the following:

[image]

If I copy the rendered form I'll get:

```
Some text...
continued in 2nd line
and third line. This is bold.

Also, here's a link:
http://www.google.com/
```

That's exactly what I need. I tried using `JEditorPane`'s renderer but it removes the `br` line breaks messing things up. Also, it adds 1 or 2 unnecessary empty lines at the bottom.

So how do I get the properly rendered text from this `HTML` snippet in regular text editor format or which query using `jsoup` would return that?

Edit:
The Java code

```
String htmlPageSource = "...";
Document document = Jsoup.parse(htmlPageSource);
String firstPostHtmlCode = getFirstPostHtmlCode();
System.out.println(firstPostHtmlCode);

public String getFirstPostHtmlCode()
{
    Elements userPosts = document.getElementsByClass("entry-content");
    Element firstPost = userPosts.get(0);

    return firstPost.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Any chance you could post the code you are using? 
You could try doing a string.replace() and replace the 'br' tags with \n.

Or, you can just keep the HTML tags and Java will recognize the 
 tags. Just enclose the text in HTML tags:

```
 string x = "<html>" + yourHTML + "</html>";
```

Not sure about the empty lines at the bottom without seeing your code.

Comment: The code is already enclosed by `<html>` tags and replacing the `<br>` tags with `\n`'s is like removed line breaks. The render engine of http://cssbox.sourceforge.net/swingbox/ is bad too but http://www.compileonline.com/try_html5_online.php is great.

Comment: The code is surrounded by '<html> tags on the web page, but you are only grabbing everything in the "entry-content" class.  You need to   add the tags back in to have Java honor the HTML code in the string.

Comment: It doesn't do a difference. I tried it. Also, retrieving the `html` from the `JEditorPane` again shows that the `html` tags are added automatically since I specified that the input is `html` code using `setContentType("text/html")`.

Comment: Ok, can you post the code you are using?  All of it?